# How to remove elements from array in D

Tags: arrays, d

I have got array of `int`'s in `tracksList_filtered` variable:

`[10422, 10681, 10421, 10392, 10616, 10589, 10581, 10423, 10743, 10213, 10613, 10609, 10427, 10484, 10031, 10169, 10695, 10580, 10171, 10703, 10486, 10631, 10642, 10137, 10566, 10704, 10420, 10525, 10209, 10658, 10617, 10127, 10128, 10391, 10602, 10587, 10030, 10393, 10660, 10614, 10485, 10523, 10215, 10029, 10655, 10210, 10659, 10041, 1075, 10425, 10724, 1068, 10657, 10216, 10662, 10211, 10410, 10601, 10644, 10212, 10074, 10696, 10424, 10208, 1074, 10394, 10419, 10426, 10705, 10038, 10661, 10040, 10165, 10396, 10168, 10653, 10610]`

I need to remove from it `10422, 10681, 10421` (not by index).

I wrote next code:

```
auto tracksList_filtered = result.array.map!(a => a[0].coerce!int); 
writeln(tracksList_filtered);
auto x = tracksList_filtered.array.remove(10422, 10681, 10421);
writeln(x);
```

It's crush with error: `range is smaller than amount of items to pop`

Example from [docs](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_mutation.html#remove) says:
"Multiple indices can be passed into remove. In that case, elements at the respective indices are all removed. The indices must be passed in increasing order, otherwise an exception occurs."

```
int[] a = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
assert(remove(a, 1, 3, 5) ==  [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]);
```

I tried to check it and placed elements for removing in increasing order:

```
auto x = tracksList_filtered.array.remove(1068,1074);
```

But got same exception.

Comment: Indices are the slot in the array, not the value in the array. Do you need the array to remain in the same order or no?

Comment: Does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user1432751's suggestion of `setDifference` is a good option, but if you do not want to sort your lists you could do:

```
auto vals = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
auto toRemove = [2,3,5];
auto res = vals.remove!(x => toRemove.canFind(x));
assert(res == [1,4,6]);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have are values in the array, not indices, so you want to use the predicate version of remove:

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_mutation.html#.remove.2

So try

```
your_array = your_array.remove!((a) => (a == 10422 || a == 10681 || a == 10421));
```

so the predicate you pass compares the values to what you want to remove.

Comment: I need to be able exclude one array from another. It's not solution for me to specifying removing elements manually :(

Comment: That predicate is a function. You can do whatever you want inside it, including checking if the value is in another array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved with `setDifference`

```
auto x = setDifference(tracksList_filtered.sort(), [1068, 1074, 1075].sort());
```

Elements *must* be sorted.